# Key Vault reference in Azure App Service doesn't resolve

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have an ASP.NET (.NET 6) application hosted within an Linux app service plan.
I'm attempting to reference a Key Vault secret within the configuration settings using the following syntax: `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://redacted.vault.azure.net/secrets/test/version)`

However, I just get a red-cross next to the setting inside Configuation blade in the Azure Portal. If I open up the setting, then I get no further information about the issue.

Here's what I have done so far:

- Followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references
- I have used the 'Key Vault Application Settings Diagnostics' tool inside the 'Diagnose and solve problems' blade; this told me everything was fine with green ticks across multiple checks EXCEPT at the bottom it came up with the following amber warning with no further information:-

> Uncategorized issues found

- I have configured the ap service managed identity and given the appropriate permissions to the principal inside Key Vault
- I have enabled 'Allow access from trusted Microsoft services' inside the Key Vault firewall.

Comment: 1) Did you enable the managed identity for the App Service?
2) Does that identity have an access policy in the Key Vault?
3) Do you have any firewall/VNets on the Key Vault?
4) Enable the Key Vault logging and check to see if there is any access from the App Service to the Key Vault.  If so, what is the HTTP response?

Comment: @MattSmall 1) yep that's configured, 2) yep access policy configured with Get Secret permission, 3) yes, KV has a firewall configured but I enabled 'Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall' 4) nope, I will try this next. thank you

Comment: I don't think that Allow Trusted Microsoft Services is not enough to bypass the firewall for your app service:

https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/01/03/key-vault-firewall-access-by-azure-app-services

Comment: @MattSmall ah yes, found the underlying error 'Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service', i.e., App Services aren't "trusted" services.  Many thanks!

Comment: are you using Vnet for this web app?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio nope, but all resolve now.  thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Adding so I can have some Internet Points*

I don't think that Allow Trusted Microsoft Services is not enough to bypass the firewall for your app service:

https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/01/03/key-vault-firewall-access-by-azure-app-services